# Conflict between Login form and Register form in the same page

Tags: php, forms, authentication

My website has a login form present in every pages (on a top-menu) so even when a user is on the Register page the login form is still available in this top-menu.

My problem is that in this specific case, when a user fills the register form and submits it, it returns the error that all fields are required to be filled. I found out that this is because my login form uses the same input names that my register form uses ( `$username` and `$password` ).

So even if the register form is filled, if i leave the login form empty it will return me this error, however if i fill the login form with anything and then submit the properly filled register, there won't be any conflicts.

Here are my `login form`, `register form`, and part of my `php code that process the register data`

login form :

```
<form method="post" action="/ftp/index.php?login=1">

        <div id="header_username">
            <input type="text" name="username" id="txt_username" placeholder="username" required="" value="" />
        <span class="username_icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div id="header_password">
        <input type="password" name="password" id="txt_password" placeholder="password" required="" />
        <span class="password_icon"><i class="fa fa-lock"></i></span>
        </div>
        <div id="forgotten_pwd">
        <a href=""><span> Forgotten Password ?</span></a>
        </div>
        <div id="submit_button">
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="<?php echo "http://$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST]$_SERVER[REQUEST_URI]"; ?>" />
        <button type="submit" name="submit" id="sub_login"><i id="submit"class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"></i></button>
        </div>
        <div id="button-border"></div>
        <div class="feedback">login successful <br />redirecting...</div>
        </form>
```

register form :

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?signup=1'; ?>" method="post">
  <div class="line"><label for="username"><?php echo lang::get("Username")?> *: </label><input type="text" name="username" id="username" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['username'])) echo $_POST['username']?>"/></div>
  <div class="line"><label for="email"><?php echo lang::get("Email")?> *: </label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['email'])) echo $_POST['email']?>"/></div>
  <div class="line"><label for="password"><?php echo lang::get("Password")?> *: </label><input type="password" name="password" id="password"/></div>
  <div class="line"><label for="password2"><?php echo lang::get("Confirm password:")?> </label><input type="password" name="password2" id="password2"/></div>
    <?php
        $rand_int1 = substr(mt_rand(),0,2);
        $rand_int2 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
        $rand_int3 = substr(mt_rand(),0,1);
        $captcha_answer = $rand_int1 + $rand_int2 - $rand_int3;
        $_SESSION['captcha_answer'] = $captcha_answer;
    ?>              
   <div class="line"><label for="captcha"><?php echo $rand_int1.' + '.$rand_int2.' - '.$rand_int3.' = ?';?> *: </label><input type="text" name="captcha" id="captcha" autocomplete="off"/></div>
   <div class="line submit" style="text-align:right"><input type="submit" class="button" value="<?php echo lang::get("Sign up")?>" /></div>
</form>

<?php endif;?>
</div>
```

php code that processes the data :

```
if (!empty($_POST)){

            $username = $_POST['username'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];
            $password = $_POST['password'];
            $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
            $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];


            // requiered fields & validation
            if (    !isset($username)
                    || $username == ''
                    || !ctype_alnum($username)
                    || gator::getUser($username)
                    || gator::getUser($email, 'email')
                    || !isset($password)
                    || !isset($password2)
                    || !isset($_POST['captcha'])
                    || $password == ''
                    || $password != $password2
                    || filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false
                    || (int)$captcha != (int)$_SESSION['captcha_answer'])
            {
                if ($username && !ctype_alnum($username)) $_POST['username'] = '';
                if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) $_POST['email'] = '';

                $errors = lang::get("All fields requiered!");
            }

            if ($errors == false){

                $reloadaction = 'thanks';
```

My question is the following :

Even though i know an alternative solution would be to rename the inputs of my register form for instance, is there a "cleaner" solution for this ? Is there instead anything i can add to my `php code that process the data` to make it ignore the login form's inputs when i submit the register form ? How do big websites deal with this type of conflicts ?

Thanks a lot for trying to help me out with this !

-Apatik

edit : my full register code :

```
 * Sign up init
 */
public function initSignup() {

    // try to activate account?
    if (gatorconf::get('signup_use_activation') && isset($_GET['activate'])){

        $key = $_GET['activate'];
        $user = gator::getUser($key, 'akey');

        if ($user){
            gator::updateUser($user['username'], array('akey' => '', 'permissions' => gatorconf::get('default_permissions_after_activation')));
            $user['permissions'] = gatorconf::get('default_permissions_after_activation');
            $this->loginUser($user);
        }

        header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url'));
        die;
    }

    $errors = null;

    if (!empty($_POST)){

        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $password2 = $_POST['password2'];
        $captcha = $_POST['captcha'];


        // requiered fields & validation
        if (    !isset($username)
                || $username == ''
                || !ctype_alnum($username)
                || gator::getUser($username)
                || gator::getUser($email, 'email')
                || !isset($password)
                || !isset($password2)
                || !isset($_POST['captcha'])
                || $password == ''
                || $password != $password2
                || filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false
                || (int)$captcha != (int)$_SESSION['captcha_answer'])
        {
            if ($username && !ctype_alnum($username)) $_POST['username'] = '';
            if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) == false) $_POST['email'] = '';

            $errors = lang::get("All fields requiered!");
        }

        if ($errors == false){

            $reloadaction = 'thanks';

            $activationkey = '';

            if (gatorconf::get('signup_use_activation')){

                $activationkey = sha1(mt_rand(10000,99999).time());
                $url = gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?signup=1&activate='.$activationkey;

                $subject = gatorconf::get('account_email_subject');
                $body = gatorconf::get('account_email_text'). "\n\n" .$url;
                $this->sendEmail($email, $subject, $body);

                $reloadaction = 'goactivate';
            }

            // homedir will be created based on username
            $homedir = gatorconf::get('repository').'/users'.DS.$username;

            // if dir does not exist - try to create one
            if ($homedir != '' && !is_dir($homedir)){
                if (!mkdir($homedir, 0755, true)) {
                    echo "ERROR: User's homedir cannot be created. Check permissions. DIR = ".$homedir; die;
                }
            }

            // add new user
            gator::addUser($username, array(
            'password' => $password,
            'permissions' => gatorconf::get('default_permissions_after_signup'),
            'homedir' => $homedir,
            'email' => $email,
            'akey' => $activationkey));

            // thanks on success or go activate!
            header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url').'/?signup=1&'.$reloadaction);
            die;
        }

    }


    if (isset($_GET['thanks'])){

        // thanks on success or go activate!
        header('Location: '.gatorconf::get('base_url'));
        die;

    }elseif (isset($_GET['goactivate'])){

        gator::display("header.php");
        gator::display("signup.php", array('goactivate' => 1));

    }else{

        gator::display("header.php");
        gator::display("signup.php", array('errors' => $errors));

    }

    gator::display("../../../style/include/footer.php");

}


/**
 *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks a lot for every answers, which were helpful.

I found that what was wrong was the submit button of my register not having a name (as you can see in my post). I added `name="register"` to it and then changed in my code `if (!empty($_POST)){` for `if (!empty($_POST['register'])){`

Seems all good now.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, give name to your submit button and just check this:

```
if (isset($_POST('submit_login'))) {
   // login related check
} 
if (isset($_POST('submit_registration'))) {
   // registration related check
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so i should put my registration code where " //login related check" is, right ? But wouldn't that be a problem later when this code is called again for the mail verification ? I've added my full register code to my post in case this was needed, thanks

Comment: If you are submitting login and registration both to same function then you have to add separates required field check for login and registration. I think your both form ending up to same condition where you are checking all required fields for registration.

Comment: thanks for your answer, yeah i just found out that the register form doesn't actually return an error because the login form has the same inputs name, but because my function just checks for every $_POST that are empty. But i still don't understand why the login form's ones are being submitted.

Comment: Oh nevermind i think i get it now. Gonna try your suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Add a hidden field to the registration form such as `<input type='hidden' name='action' value='register' />` and then check for that in your `$_POST` check code.

```
if ($_POST['action'] == 'register'){
    // Process registration code
} else {
    // Process login code
}
```

---

```
if ($_POST){ 
  if ($_POST['action'] == 'action1'){ 
    // do action 1 code 
  } 
  else if ($_POST['action'] == 'action2'){ 
    // do action 2 code 
  } 
  else { 
    // do nothing 
  }
```

Comment: hello ! thanks for your answer, i tried your suggestion but that didn't work unfortunately. It seems that this code ` if (!empty($_POST)) ` still checks for every $_POST that are empty even tho they don't belong to the register form. I don't understand why the get submitted aswell :/ i added my full php registration code to my post in case.

Comment: It's safer to get out of the practive of broad $_POST checks like that.  Set a hidden action value for all forms you use, then do something like this:(added to bottom of my answer for clearer view)

Answer (score 1):

Just do a little modification on your code for the signup page.
First give each submit button a name and than above the login php code
write

```
if(isset($_POST['submit_login'])&&!isset($_POST['submit_signup']))
```

where `submit_login` and `submit_signup` are the names of buttons
I think it should work..
best of luck